# How do I sort the lists by the second word?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have a collection with data like:

```
John eats candy
Richard runs around in the morning
Hannah drinks water
```

I divided each word, added it to the array and got:

```
[John, eats, candy]
[Richard, runs, around, in, the, morning]
[Hannah, drinks, water]
```

The output should be (the second words are sorted alphabetically)

```
[Hannah, drinks, water]
[John, eats, candy]
[Richard, runs, around, in, the, morning]
```

Here is my code:

```
        List<List<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : array) {
            String[] x = s.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                list.add(x[i]);
            }
            mainList.add(list);
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

But I do not know what to do next. How to implement a comparison of the elements and, based on this, replace the lines.
Is it right at all to divide strings into arrays to get access to the second element?
I will be happy, even if you just advise something.

Comment: **Hint 1**: first try to write a method that takes two of these lists and returns an `int` value: +1 if the second list is "greater than" the first, -1 if it's "less than" the first, and 0 if they're "equal". **Hint 2:** pay attention to the fact that some lines may only contain a single word. **Hint 3:** look up `Collections.sort()` in the Java API docs. (Or `List.sort()` if you're using Java 8.)

Comment: @biziclop I would have felt really bad closing this as duplicate, but after your comments, you made my life easier. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first attempt, you can wirte a `Comparator`:

```
class ListComparator implements Comparator<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
        return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
    }
}

mainList.sort(new ListComparator());
```

In java-8, it can be shorten to this:

```
mainList.sort(Comparator.comparing(strings -> strings.get(1))); // compare using the second element(index 1) of every list
```

Comment: it very much looks like the OP is not going to understand this...

Comment: @Eugene Makes since. But this may not be necessary, I think. Since it can solve the problem properly...